# How to binding stackpanel to some variable?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

On my application i have 3 stackpanels that their visibility is binding to 3 radio button - in case radio button A is checked => stackpanel A1 is visible ...

I want to define some variable that will be call CurrentStackPanelInFocus that will be bind to the stackpanel that is visible.

I dont know how to do it. 
I know how to write the convert - but i dont know how to do the binding.

Thanks for any help.

( the code is silverlight )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question correctly... Create a visibility converter, based on the standard one you see hundreds of times, then make the following changes:

- Use an enum for 3 state value (e.g. `enum StackPanelType{ Panel1, Panel2, Panel3}`)
- Bind each panel to that same variable (e.g. `{Binding Path=CurrentStackPanelInFocus...}`)
- In each binding specify a converter parameter, named after the enum value you want to match
  e.g `{Binding Path=CurrentStackPanelInFocus, Convertor="{StaticResource PanelConverter}" ConverterParameter="Panel1"}`
- In the converter check that the value object passed is of the type of your enum
- Convert the value to an enum and then check the string version matches the parameter
- Return Visible if the param matches the enum, else return Collapsed

Comment: Can you please explain ... i dont understand how to do it. i define the convert method ( convert from visible To stackpanel object ) and now what ?